Add 2 numbers without + or - operator | Python
I have been trying to write a logic but got test case failed.
How to improve my code ?
Code :
# Given two integers a and b, return the sum of the two integers without using the operators + and -.

a = -1
b = 1

min_val  = min(a,b)
max_val  = max(a,b)

if min_val == max_val:
    print(min_val*2)
else:
    lst = [i for i in range(max_val) ] + ([ i for i in range( min_val)])
    print(len(sorted(lst)))

Expected output is : 0
All other test cases passed
a=5 and b=5
a=10 and b=5
a=5 and b=10


I don't understand the point of this in that you still used the + operator.  Like it's an interesting challenge to test your logical thinking, I'm not trying to hate on you for trying to learn or practice or anything, but you still very much used +.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

@KingsDev : This + operator as different meaning though. It is to combine 2 list values into one

Yeah, but you're still using it in the same way. The length of the lists is equal to the numbers you're adding. If I were marking your work, you would not get points for this.

It fails because you're running range on a negative, meaning all negative numbers are treating as 0.  If you try running range on any numbers less than or equal to 0, nothing happens.  You could look into using abs to make sure they're positive; you would have to subtract the length of the negative list though, adding additional considerations.

You could look at using list.extend as described on this page.  It will add an extra line though, so it depends on if that's important to you

Can you use the operators += and -= ?

@lastchance I'd assume not, that's still pretty much just using +.

Stack Overflow's scope is limited to practical, answerable questions. If this is purely an academic exercise, it's inherently off-topic here.

Why not just use the built-in sum() function?
values = [
    (-1, 1),
    (5, 5),
    (10, 5),
    (5, 10)
]

print(*map(sum, values), sep="\n")

Output:
0
10
15
15


is this what you need?
def add_function(a, b):
    mask = 0xFFFFFFFF  #only consider the lower 32 bits of the integer
    max_int = 0x7FFFFFFF  #maximum positive integer value for a 32-bit signed integer

    while b != 0:
        a, b = (a ^ b) & mask, ((a & b) << 1) & mask

    return a if a <= max_int else ~(a ^ mask)

#run the function here
a = -1
b = 1
print(add_function(a, b))

simple way here boss;
def add_function2(a, b):
    #loop to increment/decrement a until b is zero, lol
    while b != 0:
        #if b is +, increment a and decrement b
        if b > 0:
            a += 1
            b -= 1
        #if b is -, decrement a and increment b
        else:
            a -= 1
            b += 1
    return a

#run the function here
a = -1
b = 1
print(add_function2(a, b))

please note these works for integers only. I hope that is what you were looking for. cheers!

Is their any much more simplier way to do this

This is Python. Why constrain the integer values to 32 bits?

added a simple way for you quora question

If you're using += and -= why not just do a += b?

@maxis112 without + or - Having said that, add_function2() has great comedy value

hahahahaha, technically we are not + or - a and b explicitly -- good point, feel free to modify boys

The first one is an answer from the boss (probably the way that exercise was intended to be - old school bit shifting), the second answer of someone who hasn't read the question. haha  That first one is worth an upvote! ;)

second one was a little meme tho :D LoL  cheers!

You can do it as a oneliner by using the build in sum(..):
a = -1
b = 1
print( sum([a, b]) )

result is:
0


Here are 2 easy solutions
# number 1
import operator 
operator.add(1,2)

# number 2
sum((1,2))

Edit: another one, since all operators in Python are methods, this works too:
i=5
i__add__(4)

# or even this 
getattr(i,'__add__')(4)


To add 2 numbers without using + or - or any built-in methods, you can use bitwise operations:
def add(a , b):
    while b!=0:
        carry = a & b  
        a = a ^ b          
        b = carry << 1
    return a

Say we want to add 2 (010 in binary) and 3 (011 in binary):
First iteration:

carry = 010 (2) by a & b
a     = 001 (1)  by a xor b
b     = 0100 (4) left shit carry

The second iteration repeats the same process using the previous step's results:

carry = 000
a     = 101
b     = 0000

Now b is zero, so a is result, which is 101 (5 in decimal).

This will run into an infinite loop given certain parameters - e.g., add(-1,1)
